# How to achieve "Base64 encoded SHA-1 hash of a string" in Node.js

Tags: node.js, base64, sha1

How to achieve "Base64 encoded SHA-1 hash of a string" in Nodejs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Crypto can return base64 encoded results directly:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var s = 'the quick brown fox';
var sha = crypto.createHash('sha1');
sha.update(s);
var ret = sha.digest('base64');
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using crypto?
http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

```
var ciphers = crypto.getCiphers();
console.log(ciphers); // ['AES-128-CBC', 'AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA1', ...]

var hashes = crypto.getHashes();
console.log(hashes); // ['sha', 'sha1', 'sha1WithRSAEncryption', ...]
```

From website:

> crypto.createHash(algorithm)# Creates and returns a hash object, a
>   cryptographic hash with the given algorithm which can be used to
>   generate hash digests.
>
> algorithm is dependent on the available algorithms supported by the
>   version of OpenSSL on the platform. Examples are 'sha1', 'md5',
>   'sha256', 'sha512', etc. On recent releases, openssl
>   list-message-digest-algorithms will display the available digest
>   algorithms.
>
> Example: this program that takes the sha1 sum of a file

```
var filename = process.argv[2];

var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');

var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);
s.on('data', function(d) {
  shasum.update(d);
});

s.on('end', function() {
  var d = shasum.digest('hex');
  console.log(d + '  ' + filename);
});
```